# How to specify source and destination folders (in a bulk conversion of xls to xlsx)?

Tags: excel, vba

I have files saved in xls format, auto generated from the system (daily). I need them in xlsx format before I can use it on power bi.

I found code online to do the conversion but I need to manually select the source & destination folders.

Is it possible to specify the folders instead?

I am looking to achieve automation in conjunction with power automate to trigger the VBA code for conversion. To achieve this, I need to do away with the manual selection of source and destination folders.

```vb
Sub ConvertToXlsx()

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim xWbk As Workbook
Dim xSFD, xRFD As FileDialog
Dim xSPath As String
Dim xRPath As String
Set xSFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With xSFD
    .Title = "Please select the folder contains the xls files:"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"
End With
If xSFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xSPath = xSFD.SelectedItems.Item(1)
Set xRFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With xRFD
    .Title = "Please select a folder for outputting the new files:"
    .InitialFileName = "C:\"
End With
If xRFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xRPath = xRFD.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
strPath = xSPath & "\"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While strFile <> ""
    If Right(strFile, 3) = "xls" Then
        Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)
        xWbk.SaveAs Filename:=xRPath & strFile & "x", _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        xWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    End If
    strFile = Dir
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show the code?  Have you tried anything?

Comment: hi there, this is the code that I found and tried. 
it's too long, so I have to break the code into 2 messages.

----------------------------------
Sub ConvertToXlsx()

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim xWbk As Workbook
Dim xSFD, xRFD As FileDialog
Dim xSPath As String
Dim xRPath As String
Set xSFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With xSFD
.Title = "Please select the folder contains the xls files:"
.InitialFileName = "C:\"
End With

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to manually select the source & destination folders."? Does the code open dialogs to select the folders in discussion? Such a code should be a short one. Why do you say it is so long? But **edit your question and place it there**, not in a comment!

Comment: If xSFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xSPath = xSFD.SelectedItems.Item(1)
Set xRFD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With xRFD
.Title = "Please select a folder for outputting the new files:"
.InitialFileName = "C:\"
End With
If xRFD.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
xRPath = xRFD.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
strPath = xSPath & "\"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While strFile <> ""
If Right(strFile, 3) = "xls" Then

Comment: Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=strPath & strFile)
xWbk.SaveAs Filename:=xRPath & strFile & "x", _
FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
xWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
End If
strFile = Dir
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Comment: Try using `xSPath = "C:\your real fodler path for xls files"`, instead of `xSPath = xSFD.SelectedItems.Item(1)`. Do the same with the destination folder and comment all the part of using `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, use the next adapted code:

```
Sub ConvertToXlsx()
Dim strPath As String, strFile As String
Dim xWbk As Workbook, xSPath As String, xRPath As String

xSPath = "C:\your real folder path for xls files"

xRPath = "C:\ your destination folder"

strPath = xSPath & "\"
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.xls")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Do While strFile <> ""
    'If Right(strFile, 3) = "xls" Then 'no need for it since Dir returns ONLY xls files...
        Set xWbk = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=strPath & strFile)
        xWbk.saveas fileName:=xRPath & strFile & "x", _
                           FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
             'FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook 'the above format is more suitable for a xlsx type...
        xWbk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    'End If
    strFile = Dir
Loop
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```